# Use a macro both in implementation and header and then undefine it

Tags: c

I have a macro that should be used both in my source file and header one. However I don't wan't other code linked to the final object to access that macro (more than anything else I don't want the macro to go causing unexpected errors in other files). I thought about using a macro with a long and complicated name that will be unlikely used from other code, however this solution kinda looks ugly to me. Obviously the most simple solution would be to undefine the macro in some way, however if I define the macro in the header and then undefine it – I think – I won't be able to access it anymore from the source file. What should I do?

```
// hi.h
#define string char *

void greet(string x);
```

```
// hi.c
#include "hi.h"

void greet(string x) {
    printf("Hi!");
}
```

Okay, don't kill me, this was just an example, i know `#define string char *` is horrible.

Last minute thought: Maybe I can underfine the macro at the end of the source file, is this acceptable to do?

Comment: Macros are only visible in the translation units they are defined in.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but OP wants them in their headers.

Comment: But not in the TUs *including* these headers?

Comment: *Maybe I can underfine the macro at the end of the source file* - this is useless, see my first comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Aw, I see. Does this mean that once an object file is created the macros are no longer accessible from other objects linked to it?

Comment: Once the source becomes "object", there is no such a thing as a "macro" anymore. Macro is a preprocessor construct, that is being decomposed at a pre-compilation stage.

Comment: @EugeneSh. makes sense, I didn't think about that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I do?

Pick option 1 `a macro with a long and complicated name that will be unlikely used from other code` as it's the simplest and most obvious. Do not use a complicated name - just use a name so that you and *other developers* will know it's a private symbol, that's all.

```
// hi.h

// this macro is private
#define _lib_string  char *
```

Remember about [reserved words](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). Example: https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/main/glib/glib-private.h#L32 .

> he most simple solution would be to undefine the macro in some way, however if I define the macro in the header and then undefine it – I think – I won't be able to access it anymore from the source file

If you go this way, you'll end up with spaghetti code, where some global state affects what you have. For example:

```
// hi.h
#define string char *

void greet(string x);

#ifndef FROM_HI_C
#undef string
#endif

// hi.c
#define FROM_HI_C
#include "hi.h"

void greet(string x) {
    printf("Hi!");
}
```

> Maybe I can underfine the macro at the end of the source file, is this acceptable to do?

Other files see only the header file - they are unaffected by anything in the source file.

Comment: Wow, I see thanks. So if I were developing a library, would it be better for me to choose a prefix to prepend each macro in order to create additional reserved names?

Comment: `if I were developing a library, would it be better for me to choose a prefix to prepend each macro in order to create additional reserved names?` For example, your library is named "Does Something Extra Library". You would put public symbols within `dsel_*` and private symbols in `_dsel_*`. But note that `_` followed by `_` or upper case letter are reserved, so keep your symbols within `_` and lower case letter.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could conditionally "undefine" macro at the end of the header when the a magic macro is not defined. The blessed source file would have to define this macro prior to including a header.

```
// header.h
...
#ifndef MAGIC_MACRO
#undef string
#endif

// common source
#include "header.h"

// blessed source
#define MAGIC_MACRO
#include "header.h"
```

This solution will work great as long as no macro defined inside the header uses `string` macro.

Comment: It is common practice to have something that indicates that a header file is being included by part of its implementation and thus internal details otherwise hidden should be exposed. Often the macro ends with `_IMPL_`. Like `MODULENAME_FILENAME_IMPL_`.